# How to get all tab names in tabsetpanel in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Is there any way to retrieve all tab names in a `tabsetpanel` in Shiny?
for example a code that separately gives the name of the tabs in the tabsets `tabs1` and `tabs2`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs1",
    tabPanel("Tab1"),
    tabPanel("Tab2"),
    tabPanel("Tab3"),
    tabPanel("Tab4"),
  ),
  
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs2",
              tabPanel("T1"),
              tabPanel("T2"),
              tabPanel("T3"),
              tabPanel("T4"),
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [htmltools::tagQuery](https://rstudio.github.io/htmltools/articles/tagQuery.html) to achive this:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs1",
              tabPanel("Tab1"),
              tabPanel("Tab2"),
              tabPanel("Tab3"),
              tabPanel("Tab4"),
  ),
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs2",
              tabPanel("T1"),
              tabPanel("T2"),
              tabPanel("T3"),
              tabPanel("T4"),
  )
)


tabs1_panel_names <- sapply(tagQuery(ui)$find("#tabs1")$find("a")$selectedTags(), function(x){tagGetAttribute(x, "data-value")})
print(tabs1_panel_names)

tabs2_panel_names <- sapply(tagQuery(ui)$find("#tabs2")$find("a")$selectedTags(), function(x){tagGetAttribute(x, "data-value")})
print(tabs2_panel_names)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```